# Passing ng-model in nested directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to pass my ng-model from the 'outer-directive' to an 'inner-diretive' (which is contained in the outer-directive template).

What is the correct way for doing it?

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <outer-directive ng-model="prop" />
</body>
```

and directive code:

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('outerDirective', function(){
    return {
        template: '<inner-directive ng-model="prop" />',
        link: function() { ... }
    }
});
```

Comment: Very intuitive : http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/UAvaB/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can set up a bi-directional binding (see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-), section "Directive Definition Object") with the variable in `ngModel` attribute, as with any other directives:

```html
<my-directive ng-model="foo"></my-directive>
```

```js
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" /></div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel : '=',
        },
    };
});
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/XyUGE/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! It's working beautifully
I didn't believe that it would that easy so I tried some horrible things using jquery inside the link function which none of them worked...

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of the outer model is `$pristine = true` and the input's model `$dirty = true`.  Is there a way to propagate these validation state changes to the directive-level `ng-model`?

Comment: This doesn't work if the directives have an isolated scope in later angular versions.

Comment: @BennyBottema I'm not sure to understand you. Actually, this directive *uses* an isolated scope, and perfectly works with the later versions. If you have a problem, please ask a new question, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: I'll look into it. I'll get back to it.

Comment: It seems I can't change my vote, it's locked unless you edit the post. I remember testing this code with later angular versions and that it didn't work, but I can't verify now so I'm not sure what the reason was.

Comment: `model:'=ngModel'` it allows you to have easier code to read. Means `model` could be whatever word you want

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the form in the directive and set the form dirty manually.

```
<directive directive-form="editForm" ></directive>

scope: {
 directiveForm:"="
 },
 link: function (scope, $elem, $attrs){
  scope.directiveForm.$setDirty(); 
 }
```