# AngularJS I want to fetch values for multiple field in same column

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular.

I have created a row with three select box. the add field adds same row with three select box. I want to fetch the value for Field1 , Field 2 & Field3 in same object for all rows.

I am using ngRepeat to generate the rows and each select box is an individual select directive.

[image]

Comment: please post some code that's not in a link

Comment: i have a  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in field track by key"  > in side which have three directive. The div repeats when we do add field an copies the three directive again.

Comment: Something like 

<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in field track by key">
        <multi-field-multi-select ng-model="field1[key]">
 </multi-field-multi-select>
 <multi-field-multi-select ng-model="field2[key]">
 </multi-field-multi-select>
 <multi-field-multi-select ng-model="field3[key]">
 </multi-field-multi-select>
</div> 
and in the directive i use customized ui select as mentuioned below

 <ui-select id="select_{{name}}" ng-init="init($select)"
           ng-model="field">

Comment: What does your datamodel look like? Then it would probably be easier to understand what you are trying to do. Doing a jsfiddle would also help us a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily bind the value of a select to an attribute of an object. Try something like this:

```
<select ng-model="myObject.firstValue">
    <option ng-repeat="option in firstList" value="{{option.name}}">
        {{option.name}}
    </option>
</select>

<select ng-model="myObject.secondValue">
    <option ng-repeat="option in secondList" value="{{option.name}}">
        {{option.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

To bind an ng-model to a directive use this

```
app.directive('directive', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" /></div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel : '=',
        },
    };
});
```

from here: [Passing ng-model in nested directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429958/passing-ng-model-in-nested-directives)

Comment: We have customized directive for three ui-select . 
Which is getting called from a directive with ngrepeat for adding the next row.
the main directive 
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in field track by key">
        <multi-field-multi-select ng-model="field1[key]">
 </multi-field-multi-select>
 <multi-field-multi-select ng-model="field2[key]">
 ....</multi-field-multi-select>
</div> 
add field
and customized ui-select directive 
<ui-select id="select_{{name}}" ng-model="field">
...
</ui-select>
I am able to get value for only the last select field.

Comment: Could you please add this code formatted to your example? It's hard to understand like this. What do you mean by you only get the value for the "last select field"? The third select in one row?

Comment: Hey, if this works for you it would be nice to mark the answer as correct. If you have any more questions let me know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So, it's very simple.

You have to use [$index] in ng-model for every field in order to make it unique so that your object can easily bind into all field.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.object"> 

<select name="select1" 
ng-model="vm.selectedValue1[$index]"
ng-options="field1 as field1.title for field1 in vm.field1(item)">
   <option value="">Select Item</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" 
ng-model="vm.selectedValue2[$index]"
ng-options="field2 as field2.title for field2 in vm.field2(item)">
   <option value="">Select Item</option>
</select>

<select name="select3" 
ng-model="vm.selectedValue3[$index]"
ng-options="field3 as field3.title for field3 in vm.field3(item)">
   <option value="">Select Item</option>
</select>

</div>
```